# Number of $6$ digit numbers which can be formed with $4$ specific different digits such that each digit appears at least once

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

My problem is that I'm getting different answers with two different approaches:

**Approach 1:**
I have taken two  cases:

*Case 1:* $2$ alike, $2$ alike, $2$ different

Number of ways of such a case is $$\binom{4}2\frac{6!}{2!2!}=1080$$
*Case 2:* $3$ alike, $3$ different

Number of ways of such a case is $$\binom{4}1\frac{6!}{3!}=480$$

Hence total number of numbers which can be formed are $1080+480=1560$.

**Approach 2:** I am first taking the $4$ digits and placing them in $4$ spaces in the number to be formed which can be done in $\binom{6}44!=360$ ways. Now that I have ensured that each digit has appeared once, I can fill the remaining 2 places in $4^2=16$ ways($4$ ways of filling each space and there are $2$ spaces).

So total ways is $360×16=5760$.

Where am I going wrong in any of my approaches?

Comment: Quick thought: second approach counts double: say you put the 4 digits in the first 4 spots: 1234.. and then place a 2 and a 4 in the last two spots: 123424. Your approach counts this as a different number than putting 1234 in the first, fifth, third, sixth spot and than filling with 2,4. But you get the same number! Hope this example is clear enough...

Comment: First approach does the trick: picking the numbers you'll use double (or three times), number of strings is $6!$, divide out number of amounts of placing the equal digits.

Comment: Your second approach counts each arrangement in which two digits each appear twice four times, once for each way of designating one of the two copies of each repeated digit as the representative of that digit, and each arrangement in which a digit appears three times three times, once for each of the three ways of designating one of the three copies of the repeated digit as the representative of that digit.  Notice that $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1080 + 3 \cdot 480 = 4 \cdot 1080 + 3 \cdot 480 = 5760$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach works:

1. Pick the number you will use two or three times using a combination.
2. There are $6!$ strings in 6 different digits
3. divide by the amount of possible arrangments for digits you used double.

The second approach counts double: Say you need to choose between the digits ${1,2,3,4}$ and you'll use 2 and 4 two times.

1. You put 1,2,3,4 in the first four spots, then 2 in the fifth, 4 in the sixth spot. Result: 123424.
2. You put 1,2,3,4 in the first, fifth, third and sixth spot, then 2 in the second spot and 4 in the fourth spot. Result: 123424

However, you counted those two options as being different in your second approach. This does not happen in your first approach.